# How to I insert an array into a Postgresql table using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, etl, postgresql-9.1

I have `active_record` setup to use a Postgresql database.  One of the columns is a `character varying[]`  (basically a varchar array).

Anyway, my import routine then reads a tab-delimited text file and inserts records.  All is fine until I get to an array.  The column that should be converted to an array is comma separated.  But the line itself is tab separated.

A sample of the data I'm importing looks like (tab delimited):

```
Col1      Col2     Col3                  Col4
----------------------------------------------
Apple     Pear     Sweet,Round,Green     Fruit
```

Col3 is imported like (ruby):  `col3.split(/,/)` which gives me an array in Ruby.  But active_record bombs out with:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

How can I insert that column correctly?
Also, sometimes, col3 will be NULL.

Comment: If you really want native Pg arrays, look at [ActiveRecordPostgresArray](https://github.com/tlconnor/activerecord-postgres-array) extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to insert using the following Ruby code:

```
alternatenames = '{' + s[3].split(/,/).map {|n| '"' + n + '"'}.join(",") + '}'
```

Comment: Wow.  Got two downvotes for providing the answer to my own question that works just the way I wanted it to.  Me.  The person who asked.  lol

Comment: You probably got downvoted because the solution you came up with, while it worked, isn't as elegant as others would like.  The fact they weren't able to come up with a better solution and share it with you, probably says more about them than the quality of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check Postgres' docs on this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html

You can instantiate a model using an array like [:My, :symbols] or ["My", "Strings"], however it (in my experience and form what it seems in the docs) will save the elements as strings.

```
Search.create(tokens: [{hash: 'value'}, {test: "fails"}])
=> TypeError: can't cast Hash to string
```

Where as:

```
[15] pry(main)> Search.create(tokens: [:G, :F])
=> #<Search id: 78, tokens: [:G, :F], created_at: "2013-12-18 06:29:36", updated_at: "2013-12-18 06:29:36">
[16] pry(main)> Search.last
=> #<Search id: 78, tokens: ["G", "F"], created_at: "2013-12-18 06:29:36", updated_at: "2013-12-18 06:29:36">
```

In my tests, I have a SearchEngine, Search, and Term.

```
class SearchEngine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :terms
  has_many :searches, through: :terms
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searche_engines
end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rankings
  has_many :results, through: :rankings
  has_and_belongs_to_many :terms
  has_many :search_engines, through :terms
end


# These work:
# these next two are the way postgrespl says to query against the array. You get the 
Search.where(tokens: '{A,B}')
Search.where(tokens: '{C,D}').first_or_create

[3] pry(main)> Search.where(tokens: ['C','D']).first
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information

[4] pry(main)> Search.where(tokens: '{C,D}').first
=> #<Search id: 77, tokens: ["C", "D"], created_at: "2013-12-18 06:27:24", updated_at: "2013-12-18 06:27:24">

term = "accident"
Search.where("? = ANY (tokens)", term).first
=> #<Search id: 8, tokens: ["accident", "prevention", "safety"], created_at: "2013-12-18 07:48:13", updated_at: "2013-12-18 07:48:13">
Search.create(tokens: [:Aortic, :Any, :Other, :Elements])
Search.where("'Aortic' = ANY (tokens)").first
Parent.first.first_relationships.first.second_.where("'smelly' = ANY (tokens)").first
# The next one will create one with an empty array for tokens and push it into Term.searches anyway. Same thing with 'smelly'
Term.first.searches.where("':smelly' = ANY (tokens)").first_or_create do |s|   Term.first.searches << s 
end

# These error
Search.where(tokens: "Aortic").first
Search.where(tokens: [:Aortic, :Any, :Other, :Elements]).first
```

Also, if you have nested arrays, you could do a where search with this: '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}' to find an row with column value [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]